# Combinatorics: 3 heads in succession in 5 coin tosses, using inclusion exclusion

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

This is a question from An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications, Vol. 1 Chapter 4, and doing Question 3.

[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Probability-Theory-Applications-Edition/dp/0471257087](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471257087)

Question: Find the probability that in five tossings a coin falls heads at least three times in succession.

Of course, one can solve this problem by:$P_3 = P_{[3]}+P_{[4]}+P_{[5]}$ where $P_{[i]}$ means getting exactly i heads in succession.

I'm trying to solve this using Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, and I'm stucked.

The way I'm thinking is using:$P_3 = S_3-S_4+S_5$ where $S_3$ means 3 consecutive heads show up in a sequence. This of course will include the 4 heads and 5 heads cases, and that's why there is $-S_4$ and $+S_5$

So my way is: consider 3 consecutive coins are 1 single new coin. Now your total coins are shrinked by 2, i.e. you have 3 in total (with 1 special coin that represents a HHH )

Thus the question becomes $P_1 = S_1-S_2+S_3$ since my 3 consecutive coin is '1' coin.

Therefore $S_1 = \sum{p_i}={3\choose1}\times2^2=12,S_2 = \sum{p_{ij}}={2\choose1}\times2^1=4$ and $S_3 = \sum{p_{ijk}}={1\choose1}\times2^0=1$

This leaves a wrong answer as $P_1 = 12-4+1=9$ while correct answer is 8.

Guess my question is:  My approach is probably wrong. How do I use Inclusion-Exclusion to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the stretch of three consecutive heads, and where it occurs. It occurs in positions 1,2,3, or in positions 2,3,4, or in positions 3,4,5. These three possibilities are *not* mutually exclusive, which is why you need inclusion-exclusion. Let the above three events be denoted $E_1$, $E_2$, $E_3$. Then you want
$$
P(E_1\cup E_2\cup E_3) = [P(E_1) + P(E_2) + P(E_3)] - [P(E_1\cap E_2) + P(E_2\cap E_3) + P(E_1\cap E_3)] + P(E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3).
$$
Note that in the first group the probabilities are all the same (they're each equal to $\frac1{2^3}$), but in the second group they are not all equal: $P(E_1\cap E_2)=P(E_2\cap E_3)=\frac1{2^4}$, while $P(E_1\cap E_3)=\frac1{2^5}$. This is because in event $E_1\cap E_2$ and in event $E_2\cap E_3$, you've got four heads in a row, while in the last event you've got five heads in a row. Finally in the event $E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3$ you also have five heads in a row. Adding up, the total is $\frac8{2^5}$.

Answer (score 0):

$P_3 = S_3-S_4$  you don't need to add $S_5$ back again.
You subtracted $S_4$ because you double counted the sequences of 4 heads and the sequences of 5 heads.  When you subtract $S_4$  you are removing the sequences of 4 heads and the sequences of 5 heads.... and you are done.  I understand the motivation to want to add $S_5$ back in.  But you have double counted the $S_5$  sequence in the calculation of $S_3$, and it still needs to go.